# javascript jquery drop file automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simulate file upload automatically.

There are two options:

1. clicking on UI button -> selecting file from browser file and click ok.
2. dropping a file on the UI.

In both secnarios the file should come from the file system.

Do you familiar with a way to simulate it using javascript / jquery.

It's not a test project, i'm not using selenuim or a web driver, just trying to create chrome extension that does that but it need to be relay on pure javascript/ jquery.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "simulate" ? Do you want to upload a file or not ? In HTML5, you can now [upload multiple files](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/08/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-1/) with a single input type=file, and [process files dropped on your page](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/08/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-1/), and you can [access locally with javascript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) files that have been selected by the user, to preview or [resize an image before upload](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRt6354LzJAhWEWxQKHeFOBCgQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10333971%2Fhtml5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading&usg=AFQjCNHOv4JGbtktApIx3bAoHS3pIuyIcA&sig2=xjS-Dn_KRRk9TXICE6ftbg&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU) for example. What you can't do, for obvious reasons, is go looking for files on the user's system. You have to wait for them to be brought to you.

Comment: I want to do it from javascript without the user need to select an image, but it's a chrome extension and the UI should be controller from code

Comment: So if I understand your requirement, that's something you can't do. A chrome extension  doesn't have any more access to user files than a web page. If the image file belongs to the user, you have to ask the user to get it for you. There are no work-arounds. This is fundamental.